# How to add a queueing service to store logs and notify when task is complete?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-mvc

So, there is this service in our organization. When a file is uploaded or a specific button is pressed, it displays a json message as alert "{"action": "in progress"}". But it doesn't tell you if it's still in progress or if it is completed.

I need to implement a feature that will store these messages in a queue and notify the user when the process is complete. It will also record the time of the process. The code uses Java (Spring) and Postgresql. I'm a newbie, so I don't know where to begin.

Comment: hi. Using pg_notify in Postgres alongside the NOTIFY and LISTEN for incoming events and another class to send events to those listeners.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.